# Java2wsdl (Axis1.4) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *.class

Tags: java, axis

following a simple example of an Axis 1.4 webservice using eclipse below is the layout of the project and the class files generated.

[Project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obvsd.png)

I made all jars available in my classpath:

```
C:\workspace\WorkStations\Axis14\classes> 
cho %CLASSPATH% C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\axis.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\axis-ant.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\jaxrpc.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\log4j-1.2.8.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\mail.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\saaj.jar;
C:\IDE\libs\axis-1_4\lib\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
```

When trying to generate a WSDL in command line using Java2WSDL I get the following

```
C:\workspace\WorkStations\Axis14\classes>java org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL
-o ..\calculator.wsdl -n urn:org.mos.calculator -l http://localhost:8080
/axis/services/calculator org.mos.wssample.ws.Calculator

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mos.wssample.ws.Calculator
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.setCls(Emitter.java:2079)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL.run(Java2WSDL.java:584)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL.main(Java2WSDL.java:682)
```

I tried multiple scenarios in order to make the compiler see my calculator.class  without success. Any help will be appreciated
PS: I'm using JDK8
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by refreshing eclipse, closing and re-opening command prompt. Even though I was able to navigate to all my .class files it seems the compiler was not able to find it unless refreshed.

Thanks